# How can a keyboard be shared with an iPad?

Tags: ipad, keyboard, bluetooth, sharing

What are the ways for both an iMac and an iPad to **share the same *physical* keyboard**?

If it's possible to share a *regular* **Apple bluetooth keyboard** between both devices without jailbreaking the iPad, I think it would be my favored option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Logitech made a solar bluetooth keyboard allowing keyboard to pair 3 device .

With your apple bluetooth keyboard,

JUC400 Wormhole switch will do this.
Or
If you use mac, app "type2phone"is a altinative solution.

Comment: The [Logitech k760](http://mac.appstorm.net/reviews/hardware-reviews/logitechs-k760-wireless-solar-keyboard-leaves-a-mark-on-all-devices/), I see, thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I don't think you can. Bluetooth is designed such that pairing is two-way (computer <-> device). You can't pair to a second device without un-pairing from the first device.

Comment: Sounds quite logical. Let's hope there's other ways to not have 2 keyboards on a desk.

Answer (score 2):

Bluetooth only allows pairing with one device at a time.

Answer (score 2):

This might help you, or at least lead you in the right direction.

http://modmyi.com/forums/iphone-news/716935-synergy-ipad-share-your-mouse-keyboard.html

Answer (score 2):

Theoretically using the computer as a middle man, You could set a hotkey to switch between the two? No program exists to do it though :(

Answer (score 2):

This has worked well for me - especially when I turn off the bluetooth on the current device that has the bluetooth keyboard paired, then turn on the bluetooth on the other.

Sometimes, then pair to the closest device when I power cycle the keyboard.

You have to do the initial pairing on each, but I've not had issues using one Apple Bluetooth keyboard with more than one "computer" - be it a Mac or an iOS device like an iPhone or an iPad.

You of course can't have the one keyboard drive both *at the same time* - this only works in sequence.

Answer (score 1):

It exists [for the Mac](http://houdah.com/type2Phone/index.html), so I guess it could be possible even for Windows.

> *Type2Phone*: Virtual Bluetooth Keyboard
>
> Type2Phone lets you use your Mac as Bluetooth keyboard to your iPhone,
>   iPad or Apple TV.
>
> Type on your full-sized keyboard. The text will appear on your iOS
>   device. Prepare text on your Mac and then paste it to your mobile
>   device.
>
> *Benefits*
>
> - Use your Mac as a keyboard to type SMS text messages at full speed
> - Send tweets.
> - Update your Facebook status.
> - Chat. With the comfort of a full keyboard
> - Reply to emails on accounts configured only on your iPhone
> - Paste addresses, passwords, … from your Mac to your iPhone
> - Use AppleScript to automate text input to your iPhone
>
> *Requirements*
>
> - Mac with Bluetooth enabled
> - Mac OS X 10.6.6
> - iPhone (3GS or later), iPad (all models), iPod touch (3rd generation or later). iOS 3.2 or later
> - Apple TV with software version 5.2 (January 2013) or later

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to the regular Apple bluetooth keyboard is the [Kanex Multi-Sync Keyboard](http://www.kanexlive.com/keyboard).

This keyboard can be paired with four devices, paired through Bluetooth with each of the devices just once, and you can then use the Multi-Sync Keyboard with it with just a tap of a button. Another device can be connected through USB.

This keyboard has a numeric keypad built in for those spreadsheet editing, but also features iOS-specific keys for your favorite iDevice. It operates on two AAA batteries, and can also be used in a USB-wired mode if needed.

It retails in the UK at £69.00.