# Is it possible to share a keyboard physically connected to a Windows 7 PC with an iPad 2?

Tags: keyboard, windows, ipad

I have an iPad 2 and a Windows 7 notebook.

Is it possible to, without jailbreaking, share the notebook keyboard with the iPad?

Maybe some application installed on Windows could expose keyboard through Bluetooth?

Comment: Just FYI, there's a Mac app that does this, type2phone. Not too sure if there's any Windows app that does this.

Comment: love type2phone.

Comment: I would be great to have a type2phone Windows Alternative...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [JUC400 Wormhole switch](http://www.macworld.com/article/164348/2011/12/wormhole_switch_bridges_mac_and_pc_with_one_keyboard_mouse.html) will do this.  There are a number of other solutions mentioned at [How can a keyboard be shared with an iPad?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/10027/how-can-a-keyboard-be-shared-with-an-ipad).